# Why deleting session record in django server cache doesn't make me logout?

Tags: django, session, redis

I store session in redis cache

`SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"`

I delete the record from cache, the key is "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"+the session key.

But I am still logged in after I reload the page, just got a new session. Why I am not logged out after I remove the session from the cache?

Comment: When you say you're not logged out, do you mean you can still access views that require a login?

Comment: Yes, everything remains the same

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.8 or newer, any call to `flush()` will log out the user. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush):

If you check django `logout` functionality, it uses `flush()` to logout user instead of deleting it. Here is the [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L134)

Comment: My problem is that I want to logout a session that is not the current session. Since I call the logout url from another domain. Any good to solve it?